# Numeric Like Condition - Zero or More Leading Zeros

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, wildcard

I am writing an application in `C#` and I need to filter records in a database based on a `varchar` field that has a compound id `(PREFIX#####)` set by another application.

Example Table:

```
RecordId | ObjectId | ...
1        | RFQ00001 | ...
2        | CO00002  | ...
3        | RFQ0101  | ...
4        | R101     | ...
5        | RFQ01    | ...
6        | RFQ101   | ...
```

I have a list of `ObjectId` prefixes in my application `(RFQ,CO,R,etc...)` but as you can see they are not all the same length. The numeric suffixes don't always have the same amount of leading zeros as well.

I'm confident in my `LIKE` pattern to filter by prefix `... WHERE ObjectId LIKE 'RFQ[0-9]%'`, but I'm having trouble figuring out a pattern to find a specific object.

For example if I am looking for an `RFQ` with Id `1` and I attempt to filter records from the example table above like this `... WHERE ObjectId LIKE 'RFQ[0-9]%1'`, it will return records `1` as `5` as expected, but it would also include records `3` and `6` because they end with a `'1'` (even though they are for an RFQ with an Id of 101).

Is there any way to have some kind of pattern to denote 0 or more 0s in an sql `LIKE` pattern so I could do something along the lines of `... WHERE ObjectId LIKE 'RFQ[%0]1'` (meaning starts with `RFQ` and ends with `1` separated by all 0s or nothing)? or does anyone have a better idea for handling this issue?

I have no control over how the data is entered into the table nor the ability to change the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
WHERE  ObjectId LIKE 'RFQ%1'
       AND ObjectId NOT LIKE 'RFQ%[^0]%1'
```

The `[^0]` means match any character that is not zero.

Comment: Sorry, I just added another record to the example table to show that there are not always leading zeros. This would incorrectly include record 6 because there are no leading zeros.

Comment: @Greg [No it doesn't](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7c036/1). The `1` matches `[^0]` so the `NOT LIKE` is false.